# An equivalent to first_or_create on a nested attribute in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I'm using a has many through pattern with these 3 models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_topics
  has_many :topics, through: :user_topics
end

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates :name, :uniqueness => true
end

class UserTopic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :topic
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :topic
end
```

At the moment a new topic model is trying to be created every time a new user_topic is created. I'd like to create a new topic model only if the topic name doesn't already exist, otherwise if it does, use the existing topic_id.

So something like:

```
class UserTopic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :topic
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :topic, :first_or_create(:name)
end
```

Is it possible to do something similar to this?

Comment: Why can't you use first or create?  Can you show some more code please like your controller code or a simplified version of it.

Comment: I do not know of model-only solution for this. The closest I could think of is to set the primary_key: `UserTopic belongs_to :topic, primary_key: :name`, which might change the creation factor from :`id` to `:name`. But that is not an accurate solution, and might not even work. From [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html); This doesn't seem to be supported. If you do not know a controller-way of solving this, I can post an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'd be interested to see your controller based solution. Cheers.